# How to convert seconds to milliseconds in PHP

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I want to get a difference between two dates in Php in milliseconds, How can I do this? I tried with the following code
but not working for me, I am getting the result in seconds, how can I convert to milliseconds? Here is my code.

```
$expiration_time=$row['time'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date1 = strtotime($expiration_time);  
$date2 = strtotime($date);  
echo $diff = abs($date2 - $date1);
```

Comment: One second = 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

```
$milliseconds = strtotime($date) * 1000;
```

Just multiply it by 1000.

Although I do prefer to use:

```
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Comment: you converted date to milliseconds,I want to know that how can i convert seconds ($diff) to milliseconds ?

Comment: @nishasehgal it is the same, `strtotime()` convert string date into seconds